# Null pointer exception in android using string array

Tags: java, android, exception, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am having a fragment named `Tab1` from which I am invoking a method named `sendStatusTab1` and storing the result in a String array. `sendStatusTab1` further call a method retrieveStatus in `MyDBHandler` which also returns an array.

I am getting a `NullPointerException` as you can see in the code and error provided further.

How can I correct it?

Code for `Tab1` fragment:

```
package com.example.mrbrminocha.login; 

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    ImageButton IB;
    TextView parking_left;
    String buttonID;
    String arrayStatus[] = new String[86];
    int booked_counter=0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

        arrayStatus = ((MainActivity2)this.getActivity()).sendStatusTab1(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 86; i++) {
            buttonID = "button" + (i + 1);
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id",  ((MainActivity2) this.getActivity()).getPackageName());
            IB = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(resID);
            if (arrayStatus[i].equals("Booked")) {
                booked_counter++;
                IB.setImageResource(R.drawable.grey1);
                IB.setClickable(false);
            }
        }

        parking_left = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        parking_left.setText("Parking Left" + (86-booked_counter) + "/86");
        booked_counter = 0;
        return v;
    }
}
```

Code for method showing error in `MainActivity2`:

```
public String[] sendStatusTab1(int table) {
    arraystatus = dbHandler.retrieveStatus(arraystatus, table);
    return arraystatus;
}
```

Code for a method in `MyDBHandler`:

```
public String[] retrieveStatus(String array[],int table) {

    String table_name = "";
    switch (table) {
        case 1: table_name = TABLE1;
                break;
    }
    int index = 0;
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM" + TABLE1 + "WHERE 1";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("buttonstatus")) != null) {
            array[index++] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("buttonstatus"));
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    return array;
}
```

Why am I getting `NullPointerException`, and how can I resolve this?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method   'java.lang.String[]   com.example.mrbrminocha.login.MyDBHandler.retrieveStatus(java.lang.String[], int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.mrbrminocha.login.MainActivity2.sendStatusTab1(MainActivity2.java:16 1)
    at com.example.mrbrminocha.login.Tab1.onCreateView(Tab1.java:33)
```

Answer (score 1):

your sql-query is wrong. you forgett the spaces between `from` and `where`.
this is the correct query:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE1 + " WHERE 1";
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but there was no exception and my app was running before i added some new functionality, which includes the code that i specified above. There was no problem with this query. Reply if you have any other suggestions??